# parsing a string representation of time_struct

Tags: python

I am pulling data from a db and i have some string representations of time_struct, eg:

```py
time.struct_time(tm_year=2022, tm_mon=1, tm_mday=9, tm_hour=19, tm_min=26, tm_sec=4, tm_wday=6, tm_yday=9, tm_isdst=0)
```

And I would like to parse this *string* so that i can use it as a date

I have tried: `dateparser.parse` and `eval` but no joy and i am reluctant to manually `split` it and parse it that way, as i feel there should be a better way

Comment: How do you generate this data? It looks like you did `print(some_time)`

Comment: as mentioned in OP, i am pulling it from a db, where it is stored as a string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so i have a solution of sorts by using `split` and `striptime`

I had just thought that there would perhaps be a way of using some kind of `eval` -like solution

```
from datetime import datetime
t = "time.struct_time(tm_year=2022, tm_mon=1, tm_mday=9, tm_hour=19, tm_min=26, tm_sec=4, tm_wday=6, tm_yday=9, tm_isdst=0)"
t = t.split(', tm_wday=')[0]
t = datetime.strptime(t, "time.struct_time(tm_year=%Y, tm_mon=%m, tm_mday=%d, tm_hour=%H, tm_min=%M, tm_sec=%S")
t
>> datetime.datetime(2022, 1, 9, 19, 26, 4)
```

Comment: `eval` is very rarely the way to go. Since you have a fixed format, using that as the basis for parsing like you did is the best approach.